# Extended service does not get properly injected in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a generic service that i want to extend:

```
export class GenericService() {
    constructor(protected web: WebService) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class TestService extends GenericService {

}
```

Now in my component, i'm trying to do this:

```
constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
```

What happens is that i get the service injected, but the WebService object is not injected into the testService. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: I've changed my code to look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class GenericService() {
    constructor(@Inject(WebService) protected web: WebService) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class TestService extends GenericService {
    constructor(web: WebService) {
        super(web);
    }
}
```

The code above works, but only if TestService has the constructor implemented. If i remove the constructor from TestService, injection no longer works.

Comment: How did you configure the DI?

Comment: For this service i didn't do anything special. I just specified TestService next to the component's providers.

Comment: Can you post the whole code for it? And `@(Injectable)` is the wrong usage. It should be `@Injectable()`, which you only need, if the decorated service gets something injected (it does not mark the service to be injectable which the name leads to)

Comment: It was just a typo writing pseudocode. I've actually managed to get it working, but it's a little hack'ish. I've updated my question.